# Forecasting insurance claims with multivariate historical data

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have this insurance claims data for patients suffering from a particular disease D.

After being diagnosed with disease D, patients make claim for various treatments. For each claim, there is data about the number of days after the diagnosis claim was made, the claim amount, as well as a few other categorical variables.

Using this data I have to make predictions on how much each patient is going to claim in next 12 months.

I don't have much experience with time series forecasting, therefore I'm not sure how to do it. All the tutorials I have seen have the dataset with dates for each row of data.

Could you recommend which modeling technique to use and how to fit my data in it?

Image of sample data

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to predict how much your *how much each patient is going to claim in next 12 months*, I think the best choice would be a Poisson Regression instead of Time series analysis.

First your dependent value (y) would be "claims from the patients in 2 months". Here, the response variable is count.

Now, you will have to figure out what are the factors (independent values x) that will influence your dependent (y).

Some of your data is categorical. Hence, if you are applying regression technique, the most appropriate one is the Poisson Regression Model.